# How to improve my collision logic

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, monogame

I'm developing a game, and I want to create a simple collision engine for it. The game is in 2D, tile-based, and there is only one player character in it. I am using **Monogame** (C#) to create it.

Here is my code:

```
static class character
{
    public static Rectangle currentCharacterRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Game1.human.Width, Game1.human.Height);
    public static Rectangle futureCharacterRectangle = currentCharacterRectangle;
    public static Vector2 currentRespawnPos;

    public static Vector2 currentCharacterVelocity;
    public static Vector2 currentCharacterAcceleration;

    public static int walkingSpeed = 1;
    public static int runningSpeed = 3;

    static int jumpSpeed = -14;
    static bool isJumping = false;

    static bool willBeColliding = false;

    static void getFutureRectangle()
    {
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.X += walkingSpeed;
        }
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.X += runningSpeed;
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.X -= walkingSpeed;
        }
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q) && Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.X -= runningSpeed;
        }

        if(Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && Game1.previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.Y++;
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.Y--;
        }
    }

    public static void jump()
    {
        if (jumpSpeed <= 14 && isJumping)
        {
            futureCharacterRectangle.Y += jumpSpeed;
            jumpSpeed++;
        }
        else if (jumpSpeed > 14)
        {
            isJumping = false;
            jumpSpeed = -14;
        }
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        jump();

        getFutureRectangle();

        foreach(earthTile Tile in gameWorld.tileArray)
        {
            if(futureCharacterRectangle.Intersects(Tile.currentRectangle))
            {
                willBeColliding = true;
            }
        }

        if(!willBeColliding)
        {
            currentCharacterRectangle = futureCharacterRectangle;
        }

        futureCharacterRectangle = currentCharacterRectangle;

        willBeColliding = false;
    }

    public static void Draw()
    {
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.human, currentCharacterRectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing this (perhaps simpler, or faster, or both).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found a solution:

```
static void move()
    {
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            bool isColliding = false;
            foreach (tile Tile in gameWorld.tileArray)
            {
                if (currentCharacterRectangle.Right >= Tile.currentRectangle.Left && currentCharacterRectangle.Left < Tile.currentRectangle.Right && currentCharacterRectangle.Top < Tile.currentRectangle.Bottom && currentCharacterRectangle.Bottom > Tile.currentRectangle.Top && Tile.isSolid)
                {
                    isColliding = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isColliding)
            {
                currentCharacterRectangle.X += walkingSpeed;
            }
        }
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
        {
            currentCharacterRectangle.X += runningSpeed;
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        {
            bool isColliding = false;
            foreach (tile Tile in gameWorld.tileArray)
            {
                if (currentCharacterRectangle.Left <= Tile.currentRectangle.Right && currentCharacterRectangle.Right > Tile.currentRectangle.Left && currentCharacterRectangle.Top < Tile.currentRectangle.Bottom && currentCharacterRectangle.Bottom > Tile.currentRectangle.Top && Tile.isSolid)
                {
                    isColliding = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isColliding)
            {
                currentCharacterRectangle.X -= walkingSpeed;
            }
        }
        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q) && Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
        {
            currentCharacterRectangle.X -= runningSpeed;
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            bool isColliding = false;
            foreach (tile Tile in gameWorld.tileArray)
            {
                if (currentCharacterRectangle.Bottom >= Tile.currentRectangle.Top && currentCharacterRectangle.Top < Tile.currentRectangle.Bottom && currentCharacterRectangle.Right > Tile.currentRectangle.Left && currentCharacterRectangle.Left < Tile.currentRectangle.Right && Tile.isSolid)
                {
                    isColliding = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isColliding)
            {
                currentCharacterRectangle.Y++;
            }
        }

        if (Game1.currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        {
            bool isColliding = false;
            foreach (tile Tile in gameWorld.tileArray)
            {
                if (currentCharacterRectangle.Top <= Tile.currentRectangle.Bottom && currentCharacterRectangle.Top > Tile.currentRectangle.Top && currentCharacterRectangle.Right > Tile.currentRectangle.Left && currentCharacterRectangle.Left < Tile.currentRectangle.Right && Tile.isSolid)
                {
                    isColliding = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isColliding)
            {
                currentCharacterRectangle.Y--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted if it has helped out. That way others can see this question is solved.